# How do you implement a max-heap?

Tags: data-structures, max-heap

So I've read up on heaps, and I understand the basic concept,

but not how to actually implement it.

Basically, my issue is

1. *How you know where to put a new node*?
2. *How you know which node to replace the root with when you delete*?

Comment: heaps are usually implemented using an array - did you check Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29

Comment: You use the method `heapify()` after inserting any node to the heap.

Comment: LOL @ noMAD's comment

Answer (score 0):

> How do you know where to put a new node?

Typically, although we conceptualize binary heaps as binary trees, we represent them implicitly within an array, with the elements laid out in the order you’d find them in a top-to-bottom, left-to-right scan of the tree. This makes it easy to determine where the new node goes - you place it at the end of the array after all the previous elements.

> How you know which node to replace the root with when you delete?

The standard algorithm for replacing the root goes like this:

1. Swap the last element of the heap with the root of the heap.
2. Repeatedly swap that element with its smaller child until it is smaller than all its children.